# fill main content box with grid

Tags: grids

I found this template online (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/engineering-calculation-paper) and its almost what I want, but instead of have the background blue i want to have it a grid - like a maths copy book. 
Can anyone help with this?

I have tried looking it up and can find some items where you can do a textbox (\begin{tikzpicture}...) but I want to have my main content page to contain the squares, where possible specified from the start. 
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'd suggest searching for “grid tikz” on the site.

Answer (score 1):

In line 44 und 45 there is a definition of the left and right main box, which contains the blue background definition.

Change the blue into white and it should work

Before

```
 \put(10, 10){\fcolorbox{black}{blue!10}{\framebox(155,247){}}} % Main content box
 \put(165, 10){\fcolorbox{black}{white!10}{\framebox(37,247){}}} % Margin box
```

After

```
 \put(10, 10){\fcolorbox{black}{white!10}{\framebox(155,247){}}} % Main content box
 \put(165, 10){\fcolorbox{black}{white!10}{\framebox(37,247){}}} % Margin box
```

Although I must confess, that those doubled `\fcolorbox`-`\framebox`-combo are strange.